# Can owners of GitHub repositories view stats about their repository's forks in the Traffic graph?

Tags: git, github

Can owners of GitHub repositories view stats about their repository's forks in the Traffic graph? https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-graphs/

Comment: @prasun:  GitHub is ***very much*** a tool related to programming.

Comment: What kind of stats would you be interested in seeing about forks, anyway?

Comment: but the fact that a graph feature is available or not, may not be?